# Track column data changes for review by senior analyst

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have an application that allows me to update, insert and delete data from sql server. I need to track these changes to allow a senior analyst to review the changes, and either accept or reject the changes. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I started to look at Change Tracking in SQL Server, but I'm not sure if that is what I want.

At the bare minimum, I need to know what table, record and column were updated. I also need to keep track of the old value in case the senior analyst rejects the change. User and timestamp would be nice.

Comment: Where to store the data that is changing might be complex, but you could use the before and after insert update and delete triggers to capture the changes.

Comment: If every change needs to be accepted or rejected then dont make any change at all just send the script once accepted then make the changes or if rejected no rollback operations needed no maintenance required happy days :)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your suggesting creating a new table in sql that on CRUD of any record using triggers, it will insert a "Change" record in the new table with the desired values. And then for my senior analyst to make a call to the new change table to accept or reject the changes?

Comment: @M.Ali So your suggestion is the opposite, to store the new data in a new table and only submit the change on accepting it

Comment: @M.Ali that is a good point it would be better if you are going to allow changes to be accepted and rejected to do a sort of "change Que" to be worked through.  And not actually commit the changes because that would be more difficult to roll back in the case of a rejection.

Comment: A change queue would be the most efficient thing here.  There are a few limitations.  If the data doesn't go into effect immediately (sits in a queue) you run the risk of a piece of data (cell, row, whole table) being updated more than once before it gets approved.  This makes rectifying changes complicated since an older change could be immediately overwritten without ever having really taken effect.  If you only need to keep track of the most recent change, you can add columns to the table and keep track with a timestamp column and null things out once the change is approved or rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments.

You could take the potential changes and store them in in a table that would act as a Change Que.  And from there the reviewer would work through to accept and reject.  This is opposed to actually comiting changes made and then somehow having to roll them back at some  point.  From M.Ali in the comments:

> If every change needs to be accepted or rejected then dont make any
>   change at all just send the script once accepted then make the changes
>   or if rejected no rollback operations needed no maintenance required
>   happy days :)

For the data that you would want to store for the changes, the simplest way (might not be very safe depending on access, open to suggestions), you could store the actual sql that would need to be run to make the change.

Comment: I would not have many columns for sure.  Some generic way to store them would be best.  Just a thought but, you could have one column that would store xml with the original and proposed new value in different nodes.  That way you could put almost anything in   `<changes><new>blabla</new><old>bla</old></changes>` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887(v=sql.105).aspx